# Question about statistical field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, many-body

I am starting to learn statistical field theory. The "infinite number of degrees of freedom" refers to the continuous nature of field variables in field theory, where there are infinitely many possible values or configurations. "Many-body systems" refer to systems composed of a large number of interacting constituents, such as particles, atoms, or molecules, where the behavior of each constituent is influenced by the presence and interactions with all others. My question is how these two are related or how many-body systems are often described using field theory (which deals with continuous fields and their infinite degrees of freedom).

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_field). In (non-relativistic) condensed matter theory, one often uses second quantization to describe many-body systems.